# Unzipping the multipart file - bad zipfile offset (local header sig): 4

Tags: zip, unzip

I have a file with 13 GB, which has been split equally using martipart feature in the Winzip(Windows 7).

I  uploaded the files to the Linux server and I am trying to combine the multipart file to single file. But I am running through the following error.

Files after being split,

```
  total 9646432
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 730000000 Apr 14 20:57 file.z01
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 730000000 Apr 14 20:07 file.z02
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 730000000 Apr 14 20:01 file.z03
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 730000000 Apr 14 16:30 file.z04
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 730000000 Apr 14 16:24 file.z05
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 730000000 Apr 14 16:14 file.z06
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 730000000 Apr 14 16:08 file.z07
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 730000000 Apr 14 15:51 file.z08
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 730000000 Apr 14 15:46 file.z09
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 730000000 Apr 14 15:32 file.z10
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 730000000 Apr 14 15:27 file.z11
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 730000000 Apr 14 15:20 file.z12
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 730000000 Apr 14 14:28 file.z13
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 349166077 Apr 14 21:00 file.zip
```

Command in server,

```
 #zip file.zip
```

I am running into the error,

```
Archive:  file.zip
warning [file.zip]:  zipfile claims to be last disk of a multi-part archive;
attempting to process anyway, assuming all parts have been concatenated
together in order.  Expect "errors" and warnings...true multi-part support
doesn't exist yet (coming soon).
 file #1:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  4
```

I have tested the same for test file with 27MB ,

```
 #ls
test.z01  test.z02  test.z03  test.z04  test.z05  test.zip


 [tbabu@fgtd-301705-130558-app001 .tbabu]$ unzip test.zip
Archive:  test.zip
warning [test.zip]:  zipfile claims to be last disk of a multi-part archive;
attempting to process anyway, assuming all parts have been concatenated
together in order.  Expect "errors" and warnings...true multi-part support
doesn't exist yet (coming soon).
file #1:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  4
file #2:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  207105
file #3:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  209345
..
..
file #302:  bad zipfile offset (lseek):  2924544
file #303:  bad zipfile offset (lseek):  2940928
..
..
..
inflating: en_US/1/2.zip
..
..
..
```

I am able to combine the files in the test eventhough I get above message.

Why is not working with the 13Gb file??

Assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `cat`-based solution didn't work for me, but merging the files using `zip -F file.zip --out file-large.zip` and then `unzip file-large.zip` did work.

Comment: Same here: the cat solution lead to some files not being unzipped. This solution worked.

Answer (score 7):

You could try

```
cat test.z* > hugetest.zip
unzip hugetest.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

## zip & unzip & diff

```
zip -s 1m -o archived.zip test.pdf

cat archived.z* > merged.zip
unzip merged.zip

mv test.pdf test.pdf.origin
diff test.pdf test.pdf.origin
```

Comment: Please explain your answer